# Python dataclass inferred fields

Tags: python-3.x, python-dataclasses

Is it possible in python to have fields in a dataclass which infer their value from other fields in the dataclass? In this case the `cacheKey` is just a combination of other fields and I don't want to mention it explicitly in the object instantiation.

```
@dataclass
class SampleInput:
 uuid: str
 date: str
 requestType: str
 cacheKey = f"{self.uuid}:{self.date}:{self.requestType}" # Expressing the idea
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **post_init** to use the other fields:

```
@dataclass
class SampleInput:
   uuid: str
   date: str
   requestType: str

   def __post_init__(self):
        self.cacheKey = f"{self.uuid}:{self.date}:{self.requestType}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a Python property in your class definition:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class SampleInput:
    uuid: str
    date: str
    requestType: str

    @property
    def cacheKey(self):
        return f"{self.uuid}:{self.date}:{self.requestType}"
```

This is the most straightforward approach. The only drawback is that `cacheKey` won't show up as a field of your class if you use serialization methods such as `daclasses.asdict`.